# Alignment of TextView and ImageView

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-imageview, textview

I am trying to set a text and Image (Small image) in one single line. Requirement is that Text should be left aligned and Image should be right aligned. If the text is big then it should not overlap the image and rather it should come in 2 or more lines.
I am trying this with following piece of code but it's not working. 1st of all Image is not right aligned and if text is big, Image is not coming at all, only text is coming in multiple lines:

```
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/answerTextView"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="left"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/answer_size"
                    android:textStyle="bold" >
                </TextView>

                <View
                    android:layout_width="3dip"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
                </View>

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/congratsImageView"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/congrats_img_width"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/congrats_img_height"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="false"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY" >
                </ImageView>
            </LinearLayout>
```

I tried with RelativeLayout also, in that case Image and Text both are aligned left and the Image is overlapping the text on left.
Note that there are other fields also above and below LinearLayout here and I am stting the image from Java method at runtime.
Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use **android:weight** Propert to give them equal spaces.

Look I have modified your code. It will 100% work use it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"        
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/answerTextView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:text="Hello world.Hello world.Hello world.Hello world.Hello world.Hello world. "
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textStyle="bold" >
        </TextView>

        <View
            android:layout_width="3dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        </View>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/congratsImageView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:adjustViewBounds="false"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" >
        </ImageView>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: @Sid just get back to me if it gives problem or if you have any question.

Comment: Thanks Nikhil, Now Text is left aligned and Image right aligned (as per requirement), but now height and width of image is not fixed (I am explicitly setting here), It's setting width and height based on the space available after text. Please help if u can.

Comment: @Sid I am not understanding please explain your problem. You wanna fix the image height and width right.

Comment: It's like If you have small text in textview (say Abcd) then Image width is bigger and if we have large text in textview (say thisisveryveryveryveryveruyveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryverylargetext) then image width is very small.That's image width is not fixed. Look at the code I gave above android:layout_width="@dimen/congrats_img_width"

Comment: @Sid If you want to do so you ca use Layout:height and layout:width property of the image and give it in xxdp as much you want.

Comment: Yes I am doing that. i am setting image width as android:layout_width="@dimen/congrats_img_width" Please have a look at my original code.

Comment: @sid ya because image size is fixed you want image size as much as your text quantity this is you want

Comment: my image size should be fixed say 50dp, but should be aligned to right.

Comment: @Sid now I am understanding because we have specified the weight don't change image width. If you want to reduce  image width reduce your file size.

Comment: Thanks mate, but I think still you are not clear what I want. The image width should be fixed to 50dp and should be aligned right. Text should be aligned left and if it is a large text It can go upto multiple lines, but in any case image width should be constant.

Comment: @sid means you dont want to divide them equally this is thing

Comment: Yep anyways I figured that out, I removed  android:layout_weight="1" from ImageView and it's working fine. Thanks a lot for your help. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code -

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"        
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/answerTextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:text="Hello world.Hello world.Hello world.Hello world.Hello world.Hello world. "
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textStyle="bold" >
    </TextView>

    <View
        android:layout_width="3dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </View>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/congratsImageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" >
    </ImageView>
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```